# Spark OutOfMemoryError when taking a big input file

Tags: apache-spark

I have a spark application that reads a file with 100 million lines (each line has a code, such as `US1.234.567B1`) and gets some patterns out of it, as follows:

```
  val codes = sc.textFile("/data/codes.txt")

  def getPattern(code: String) = code.replaceAll("\\d", "d")

  val patterns: RDD[(String, Int)] = codes
    .groupBy(getPattern)
    .mapValues(_.size)
    .sortBy(- _._2)

  patterns
    .map { case (pattern, size) => s"$size\t$pattern" }
    .saveAsTextFile("/tmp/patterns")
```

I am running this on master=local[*], and it fails with `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded`.

Why is that?

I thought that Spark can handle any size of input, as long as it has enough hard disk space.

Comment: two docs explaining why groupBy should be avoided:
https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/best_practices/prefer_reducebykey_over_groupbykey.html
https://github.com/awesome-spark/spark-gotchas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long short you're trying to use Spark anti-pattern:

```
.groupBy(getPattern)
.mapValues(_.size)
```

that can be easily expressed for example as:

```
codes.keyBy(getPattern).mapValues(_ => 1L).reduceByKey(_ + _).sortBy(_._2, false)
```

> I thought that Spark can handle any size of input.

It usually can scale out as long as you don't make it impossible. `group` / `groupByKey` on RDDs create local collections for each key. Each of these hast to in the memory of a single executor.

Answer (score 1):

Yes spark can process very large files, but the unit of parallelism is the executor. 'Out of memory error' is because the spark executor memory or the spark driver memory is insufficient. Please try increasing spark.executor.memory and spark.driver.memory and also tune the number of executors before you submit the job.

You can set these values in a property file or in SparkConf or directly in command line  during spark-submit. Link http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html