# reduceByKey equivalent on PySpark Dataframes

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to do some data analysis that involves aggregations using the pySpark Dataframe API. My understanding is that the `groupBy()` operation is equivalent to the `groupByKey()` Spark command. Is there a command on the Dataframe API that is equivalent to Spark's `reduceByKey()`? My concern is that `groupBy()` seems to collects all values for a key into memory, which is not great in terms of performance.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DataFrame groupBy behaviour/optimization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32902982/dataframe-groupby-behaviour-optimization)

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34249841/spark-dataframe-reducebykey-like-operation

Comment: So this means `groupBy` works like `reduceByKey`? It is not entirely clear to me that this is always the expected case.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39796493/spark-outofmemoryerror-when-taking-a-big-input-file#comment66900222_39796493 - second link explains some cases.